# How to select a row of table using foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (first is account and second is friend)
where account looks like

// tabble account

```
id | name
1  | bob
2  | robin
3  | chan
4  | jack
```

// id is primary key

// table friend

```
id | user_id | frn_id
1  | 2       | 4
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 1       | 3
```

// user_id and frn_id are foregin key from primary key of account

The select result should look like this

```
id | user_id | frn_id
1  | robin   | jack
2  | bob     | robin
3  | bob     | chan
```

then how to select from table friend in a such a way so that instead of showing user_id and frn_id, I want to show name from table account.

Comment: what you need is an INNER JOIN. If you're not familiar with it, almost any introductory SQL tutorial or documentation will show you

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: Learn some SQL.  If you can't even do the simple `JOIN`, you should not touch the database, and hire someone who can.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I have done this with inner join

Comment: @Eric The OPs has asked a question in a clear and precise manner. I don't see anything wrong here. Stackoverflow is not a place for experienced programmer only, but also welcomes beginner - https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some inner join query and it works for me

```
select f.id, a1.name as 'user', a2.name as 'friend'
from friend f
INNER join account a1 on a1.id = f.user_id
INNER join account a2 on a2.id = f.frn_id
ORDER BY f.id
```