# How to display data using more than 2 foreign key in sql?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 4 tables in my database which is student, committee, event, evtstatus. I need to retrieve some data from each table.

I have already try it in mysqli still i get some errors as like

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Student\index.php on line 106

student:

```
   student_id | name     | member_type 
   10         | Ali      | Not A Member         
   14         | James    | Member of Taekwando 
   15         | Bakar    | Not A Member
```

committee:

```
   committee_id  | email             | image        |
             1   | abc@gmail.com     | pic.jpg      |
             2   | abccd@ymail.com   | pic1.jpg     |
             3   | shdhs@yahoo.com   | pic2.jpg     |
```

event:

```
   event_id  |   event_name     | start_date            | committee_id |
         11  | Sport Meeting    | 2018-12-19 20:00:00   |       1      |
         12  | Yamacha Tonite   | 2018-12-18 21:00:44   |       1      |
         13  | Family Gathering | 2018-12-17 22:00:44   |       3      |
```

evtstatus:

```
   evt_id   | event_id | student_id    | status_info |
      111   |     11   |       10      |   Not Going |
      112   |     12   |       14      |   Going     |
      113   |     13   |       15      |   Going     |
```

The 'committee_id' in both the event and committee are the same. 'event_id' in event and evtstatus are also same.

I want to select event name, start_date, student_id, member_type, status_info which under committee_id == 1

So the query result should be (in this case)

```
Sport Meeting | 2018-12-19 20:00:00 | 10 | Not A Member        | Not Going
Yamacha Tonite| 2018-12-18 21:00:44 | 14 | Member of Taekwando | Going
```

Comment: how is the code that gives the error?

Comment: You can use SQL JOIN, I already ask a similar question. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179108/how-to-select-a-row-of-table-using-foreign-key-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Using typical `JOIN`s you can do this:

```
select
  e.event_name,
  e.start_date,
  es.student_id,
  s.member_type,
  es.status_info
from evtstatus es
join student s on s.student_id = es.student_id
join event e on e.event_id = es.event_id
join committee c on c.committee_id = e.committee_id
where e.committee_id = 1
```

Comment: @Jane . . . This seems like the right answer.  How does it not work?

Comment: Guess What The Impaler? Your answer is worked for me... Thank you so much once again. I was trying this for past 1 week and now its works. :)